# Poor Post performance

Tags: c#, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

Im trying to create  a simple tool to test a webservice post performance

```
private void post()
{
   string url = "http://myserver";
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      using (var wb = new WebClient())
      {
         var data = new NameValueCollection();
         data["name"] = "test1";
         data["email"] = "moretest";
         var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
      }

    };

}
```

I using a backgroundworker but no matter if Im using 3 og 50 background workers Im not able to get higher uploads speeds than 0.1 - 0.3 Mbps

How can I optimize the code?

Comment: 1.your not using client so remove it from the code,

Comment: 2. try   var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = Url }; HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("update action off url", content).Result;

Comment: 3. I am not sure what your trying to do with threading this (worker) could you explain more.

Comment: 4.I mean how did you even measure it... measuring this in Mbps seems weird/odd.

Comment: @Seabizkit For measuring I used taskmanager. What is the best way to convert the NameValueCollection to HttPContent

Comment: see var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.Default, "application/json");

Comment: using task manager is really WRONG for measuring performance

Comment: I know i cant use the task manager to do any measuring, however my goal was to generate enough posts to put some load on the server but Im just not able to

Comment: depending on how you write it, but from what im seeing here... you are more likely to max out your CPU than the network activity.... kind hard to explain... but you are not streaming any measurable amount of data... i.e. even if you sent 10 000 at the same time the network foot print would be say 2kb x 10 000 which is like nothing. so lets say it was 100 000 its would still be like nothing in terms of bandwidth usage but the cpu power need to do that each second would be a lot. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I changed the code abit and got a bit better performance. But then I started to run out of sockets :(... Guess its never as simple as it might seem